# Is there any way to quick pair my bluetooth headphone?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones

To disconnect my bluetooth headset is easy and just turn off my bluetooth. But I need to switch 3 pages in 4 steps to pair my bluetooth headset.

- Unlock my iPhone
- Click Setting Icon
- Click Bluetooth Option
- Click My Headset device shown in the list.

Is there any way to quick pairing my bluetooth device in one or two step? 
Is it possible to add a specific device pairing shortcut on the springboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Toggle on Bluetooth on your phone
2. Switch the headphones on
3. Press the play/pause button on your headphones
   They should connect without having to do anything else. They *should* connect without step three but it doesn't hurt to force the headphone to go looking for the phone.

Comment: Yeah it works. It indeed automatically search and be connected with my phone.

Comment: Quick note: don't switch on the headphones and keep holding down the power button for pairing mode. That's for *new* pairings. Just power on, play button. Ten minutes of my life I'll never get back.

Comment: On my pair of Beats Studio 3, this seems to reconnect to the most recent sound source that is in range. But if I have, say, a Macbook Pro and an iPhone, have my headphones connected to the Macbook and want to switch to the iPhone, this just reconnects to the Macbook.